# Tumblr API - How to create an array that then will be used by a script to search images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tumblr

I'd like to create an array (or something, I'm not sure if I'm right) that will hold various tags, and then the script will chose some of them (not only one of them) and post images from that tag. So far with help of fellow programmers I managed to create a simple script that grabs images from one tag, and I'd like to expand on that. Here's the full code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function (){
    var link = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=vhs";
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url : link,
      dataType: "jsonp", 
      data: {
          api_key: "PgAKpKfv1Tcjo1uhsKEuriThhwH9XDJonRobaGwckw8RJt2tos"
      }
    }).done(function( data ) {
      $.each(data.response, function(){
        var _photos = this.photos;

        $.each(_photos, function(){
          $('body').append("<img src='" + this.original_size.url + "'/>");
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

According to a comment there is no way to grab images from more than one tag at once. How to modify the existing one to grab a random one from an array?

Comment: The tumblr API only allows 1 tag per search, so you would have to have multiple AJAX calls for each tag, and then merge them together

Comment: How to create a function that will select a random tag from an array of them? This way I can create one big array and a few scripts to grab random tags and display images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have an array of tags, then iterate it to call and retrieve items from each and one of them.

i.e.:

```
tags = ['george', 'of', 'the', 'jungle'];
iterateTags(tags);

function iterateTags(tags)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        tag = tags[i];
        endURL = tagsURL + tag;

        callTumblr(endURL);
    }
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/4awvc3m6/6/

Comment: Hmm.. When I enter some unrelated tags like 'cyberpunk' and 'horror' it doesn't show anything at all. I think that it works only if both tags are present in the same image. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Lnvz Yea, there was an issue with `tagsURL`, which now has been fixed

Comment: How to make it show more images though? It shows 2 or 4 max.

Comment: It grabs images from the first tag but doesn't work if I add more.

Comment: What I mean is: if I put 'futuristic' as the first tag in the array, and add 'manga+horror' next, it shows only futuristic images.

Comment: @Lnvz It was your initial `$.each` fault when iterating photos. I've updated the link